# srno value is incremented but when page is refreshed then its value again reset and shows srno=1. how to increment value

Tags: gridview, sharepoint-2010

```
    HiddenField HFSN = new HiddenField();
    DataTable table= new DataTable();
    DataTable result=new DataTable();
    private int srno = 1;
    private string headlines;
    private string date;
    Button btn = new Button();

    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/GridViewWP/GridView8/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx";
    private Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView _grid;
```

this is my main method.
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

```
        btn.Visible = true;
        btn.Text = "Show";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        _grid = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView();
        _grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _grid.AllowPaging = true;
        _grid.PageSize = 5;
        //_grid.PageIndexChanging += _grid_PageIndexChanging;
       foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            _grid.Columns.Add(new BoundField()
            {
                DataField = column.ColumnName,
                HeaderText = column.ColumnName
            });
        //_grid.DataSource = table;
        this.Controls.Add(_grid);
       // _grid.PagerTemplate = null;
        //_grid.DataBind();
        _grid.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

one time btn click show only one row. as each time button is pressed it will show a new row which is statically added in GetDataTable().
   ********** void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        srno = Convert.ToInt32(HFSN.Value);
        DataRow[] rows = table.Select();
        if (srno <= rows.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {

                if (rows[i]["srno"].ToString() == srno.ToString())
                {

                    headlines = rows[i]["headlines"].ToString();
                    date = rows[i]["date"].ToString();
                }

            }

            if ((srno) == 1)
            {
                result.Columns.Add("srno", typeof(int));
                result.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
                result.Columns.Add("Headlines", typeof(string));
            }
             result.Rows.Add(new object[] { srno, date, headlines });
        }

        srno++;
        //HFSN.Value =Convert.ToString(srno);

        _grid.DataSource = result;
            _grid.DataBind();
           // DataTable table = GetDataTable();

            _grid.Visible = true;


    }    ***********



    private DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
      //  DataTable result = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("srno", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("headlines", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(System.DateTime));
        //for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Chinese Troops Begin Withdrawing from Ladakh Hours after Xi-Modi meet", "2014-09-22" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "BJP-Shiv Sena Alliance of 25 years on verge of Collapse", "2014-09-21" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Meet THe Highest Female Executive In the World", "2014-09-22" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Indian Muslims will Live And Die For India,PM Says", "2014-09-21" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Two Doctors, Who got stuck in J&K floods, turn saviours for this town", "2014-09-21" });
        return table;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Sessions instead private variable
2. Use a asp.net hidden control to store the value. you will get benefit of viewstate.